# Why do I need a userAccessToken for /statuses request?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the PHP SDK, I am trying to query for the statuses of a page. But the Graph Explorer returns an error `(#100) Requires user session`. Why is that? Querying for the feed of the page works without user authorization and statuses are just a subset of the feed, aren't they?

Is there any way I can extract from `/feed` or `/posts` what `/statuses` would return?

Comment: Documentation says that no access token was required to read publicly available statuses … so I’d say it’s a bug if it says _Requires user session_ – maybe go file one here: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/